# How to install multiple PHP instances and configure for Apache

Tags: centos, software-installation, apache-httpd, php

I need to upgrade my PHP installation on CentOS 6 from 5.3 to 5.5. While I have a couple of webprojects running I like first to install the new PHP in parallel and switch back to the old one if problems are occurring.

- How do I install PHP 5.5 on CentOS in parallel and keep the old one?
- How do I configure Apache to take the new PHP instance?
- Is there a possibility on Apache to specify for each virtual host which PHP instance has to be taken?
- How do I uninstall the old version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a couple of tutorials which shows how this can be achieved:

[solution 1](http://blog.servergrove.com/2011/08/22/how-to-setup-multiple-php-versions-on-apache/) - using fast cgi instead of mod_php

[solution 2](http://mossiso.com/2009/09/02/multiple-php-instances-with-one-apache.html) - runn a single instance of Apache, and run one instance of PHP as a module, and other installs as CGI.

Comment: Can you please incorporate some of the details from those links in your A? Link only A's is discouraged since links often become stale and/or broken over time, in which case your A becomes useless to future passer-bys.